# Unshelve in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3

Tags: intellij-idea

I've recently updated IDEA and now can't find neither unshelve feature, nor shelves view. Where are they?

Shelving works fine, I see patch file. But the only way to restore it is to take this file from IDEA secret folder and perform "Apply patch" with it. Is it OK?

Comment: Are you talking about shelving in general or as part of a VCS (like git)?

Comment: I am about IDEA's own shelve tool. It can be found in VCS menu, after "Create Patch" and "Apply patch"

Answer (score 0):

Often after an upgrade (especially when you install to a different directory) IDEA loses its index of what patches were on the shelf.

Thankfully, the patch files are still there - IDEA just doesn't remember about them any more.

Look in your **.IntelliJIdea/config/shelf** directory and you should find some **.patch** files (each one named after with the name of the changeset that you shelved).

You should be able to "Apply Patch" these files from your CVS menu like normal patch files (that's all shelve/unshelve does anyway, nothing fancy going on - I've done it before and it worked fine).

If you haven't changed anything about your installation, the .IntelliJIdea directory should be in your home directory (not sure, I always change mine to sit underneath my IDEA install directory).

Comment: I know where IDEA stores patch files, thanks. Question is not about this.